# How can I write a advanced pipeline-aware PowerShell function which also accepts array input?

Tags: powershell, function, pipeline

## TL;DR

How can I write a advanced pipeline-aware powershell that can complete the following?

```
<#
Test-One accepts [T] and returns [U]
Test-Two accepts [U] and returns [V]
[T], [U], and [V] may be enumerable by the pipeline, which should be prevented
#>

<#
No pipeline, single-input
Accepts [T] and returns [V]
#>
$input = ...
$cache = Test-One -Input $input
$output = Test-Two -Input $cache

<#
With pipeline, single-input
Accepts [T] and returns [V]
#>
$input = ...
$output = $input | Test-One | Test-Two

<#
With pipeline, multiple-inputs
Accepts [T[]] and returns [V[]] through pipeline which accepts [T] and returns [V]
#>
$input = @(..., ...)
$output = $input | Test-One | Test-Two

<#
No pipeline, multiple-inputs
Accepts [T[]] and returns [V[]] by directly returning [U[]] in between
#>
$input = @(..., ...)
$cache = Test-One -Input $input
$output = Test-Two -Input $cache
```

## Full Problem

I am writing a PowerShell module and I've just finished implementing some basic logic.
It currently contains 2 functions:

```
Function Get-HelpCommentTokens
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]
        $Command
    )
    # Logic
    # Returns [Token[]]
}

Function Get-TextFromCommentTokens
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [Token[]]
        $Tokens
    )
    # Logic
    # Returns [string[]]
}
```

Current usage:

```
# No pipeline, single-input
$HelpTokens = Get-HelpCommentTokens -Command "help"
$HelpText = Get-TextFromCommentTokens -Tokens $HelpTokens
```

I am now adding support for both pipelines and multiple inputs

Their usages:

```
# With pipeline, single-input
$HelpTokens =  "help" | Get-HelpCommentTokens | Get-TextFromCommentTokens # Should accept [string] and return [string[]]
# With pipeline, multiple-inputs
$HelpTokens =  "help", "other" | Get-HelpCommentTokens | Get-TextFromCommentTokens # Should accept [string[]] and return [string[][]]
# No pipeline, multiple-inputs
$HelpTokens = Get-HelpCommentTokens -Command "help", "other" # Should accept [string[]] and return [Token[][]]
$HelpText = Get-TextFromCommentTokens -Tokens $HelpTokens # Should accept [Token[][]] and return [string[][]]
```

For the `with pipeline, single-input` and the `with pipeline, multiple-inputs` cases, I don't need to do anything, as the builtin pipeline engine handles them quite well. It's the `no pipeline, multiple-inputs` case that is the problem, as I can't just make the parameters arrays, as PowerShell flattens the output with its pipeline engine and casts them to single item arrays (e.g. `@(@(1, 2), @(3, 4)) -> @(@(1), @(2), @(3), @(4))`, thus disallowing this solution:

```
Function Get-HelpCommentTokens
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]
        $Command
    )
    # Foreach logic
    # Returns [Token[][]]
}

Function Get-TextFromCommentTokens
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Token[][]]
        $Tokens
    )
    # Foreach logic
    # Returns [string[][]]
}
```

Another possible solution is to make a parameter set just for pipelines, but I hope to use the same parameter names for both pipeline and non-pipeline input.

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: You should use a [`process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods#process) for this

Comment: You can use the comma operator to prevent array unrolling: `, $array` outputs the array as-is. Though PowerShell functions are not supposed to "return" arrays as a whole, as in traditional programming languages. They should _output_ array elements one-by-one. E. g. your function `Get-HelpCommentTokens` should output `Token[]` from within the `foreach` loop. If at some point you need to store the output as a variable of `Token[][]`, then you just assign the output of the function and PowerShell will build up this two-dimensional array for you.

Comment: @zett42 Will this choke the pipeline?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you replaced the body comments (eg. `# Returns [string[][]]`) with code that actually reproduces the behavior you're describing :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The code is over 200 lines. Should I still post it?

Comment: Should I use a special pipeline parameter set with the same parameters?